# Data Table to array in jquery

Tags: jquery, sql, arrays

I have a SQL data table. It containing two column data.I initialized an array in my script file using `JQUERY`. I want to send the data table data to my `array`.

```
    <script type="text/java script">
     $(document).ready(function () {

     goog = [["6/22/2009", 10], ["6/15/2009", 15], ["6/8/2009", 10], ["6/1/2009", 10], ["5/26/2009", 16],
  ["5/18/2009", 11], ["5/11/2009",8], ["5/4/2009", 20], ["4/27/2009", 14], ["4/20/2009", 17],
  ["4/13/2009", 12], ["4/6/2009", 11], ["3/30/2009", 14], ["3/23/2009", 14], ["3/16/2009", 20],
  ["3/9/2009", 10], ["3/2/2009", 5], ["2/23/2009", 9], ["2/17/2009", 9], ["2/9/2009", 11],
  ["2/2/2009", 12]];
</script>
```

Now am creating arrays manually. But I want to load the data from data table.

Comment: How you conect to the database and get the data. Need more details

Comment: I connect SQL data Table to my data table in my Backend using c#.

Comment: you need to create a web service on backend which would connect to DB and return the array what your expecting. then you need to make ajax request to this service to read the data, which you can process it after receiving it successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I will try....

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: which language use in backend?

Comment: c# @Darshak Gajjar

Comment: Create one WEB API and using ajax call you can easily get data in array..i hope you know how to create webapi?

Comment: I am trying..@Darshak Gajjar

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you Web API Method for C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

 [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public object GetData()
        {
            try
            {

                DataTable dt = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataTable(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetATMDetails");
                //var dt = DataTableCompressor.Decompress(clsServiceInitialization.Instance.proxyEstimationInfoService.GetAllCity());
                if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    return new
                    {
                        Data = dt,
                        ErrorID = 0,
                        Message = "User"
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new
                    {
                        ErrorID = 0,
                        Message = "No records retrieved."
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What are the assembly reference to be added @ Darshak Gajjar